# How to get a specific key or value from a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I honestly tried to look at a lot of posts but I am not sure what is the correct way of getting a specific key from a ConcurrentHashMap.

1. How to get the first key in a ConcurrentHashMap?
2. How to get the key on first encounter of a certain value?
3. How to update the value of a specific key?

Comment: What is a first key in a map?

Comment: http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.Entry.html

Answer (score 6):

Okay, lets tackle these questions one by one:

1) You cannot. A `ConcurrentHashMap` has no order. There is no "first" and no "last".

2) A `ConcurrentHashMap` provides an `entrySet` which is "weakly consistent", so that if the content of the `Map` changes during iteration you might see the changes, you might not:

```
public static <K, V> Optional<K> getKeyForVal(final V val, final Map<K, V> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(val))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .findFirst();
}
```

Again, there is no "first" this is just the first one *encountered* during iteration.

3) This is easy, just add the same `key -> value` pair again, this will update the value for a particular key.

So the main takeaway here is that a `ConcurrentHashMap` **has no order**. The order of iteration over a `ConcurrentHashMap` is **undefined** and may even change between different iterations. There is no "first", no "last".

Something like [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) does have an ordering, it's sorted by the order of the keys as defined by a `Comparator`. So that would have a "first" and a "last" element.

Comment: fwiw, even though Shog9 doesn't want me to tell you this, I did already +1 your answer. :)